# Qt Enterprise for IMX6 not using Hardware Acceleration?

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, qt5, hardware-acceleration, qtwebengine

We built an application which uses QT WebEngine to test WebGL functionality, it worked however the CPU utilization was very high (>30%) for rendering some sine waveforms, the root file system was provided by QT Enterprise as described here for IMX6

http://doc.qt.digia.com/QtEnterpriseEmbedded/qtee-preparing-hardware-imx6sabresd.html

On inspecting the root file system we found that there were no GPU drivers (usually libVivante.so and libVivante.ko for IMX6), so it looks like all the GL rendering is being done by CPU instead of GPU and thats the reason for high CPU Utilization, Does anybody know any other ways to enable hardware acceleration for WebGL in the QT WebEngine?

Answer (score 3):

Qt WebEngine requires hardware acceleration to composite the layers of the page and you would probably not be able to see anything on the screen without it.

Chromium, behind Qt WebEngine, is quite a beast and is more designed for perceived smoothness than to yield CPU cycles; it will use all the resources it can to achieve this.

Any JavaScript WebGL call will go from the main render thread, then to the GPU process main thread to be decoded into GL calls to the driver. Each different WebGL canvas will trigger a different FBO to be used and bound, requiring GL context switching, and as often as possible, the latest state will trigger the Chromium compositor to kick in, send all the delegated scene to the browser process, to finally end in QtQuick's scene graph thread to be composited.

All this to say that a single JavaScript WebGL call triggers a much bigger machine than just telling OpenGL to draw those geometries. A CPU usage of 30% on this kind of device doesn't seem anormal to me, though there might be a way to avoid bottle necks.

The most efficient this could get is by having a custom QtQuick Scene Graph geometry as shown in this example: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-customgeometry-example.html, but even then I wouldn't expect a CPU usage under 10% on that device.